# Animation speed is degrading in javaScript

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating various ul elements in javaScript and then inside setInterval ,i am animating these uls by adding li elements and decreasing the marginTop of each ul. Initially it runs with the proper speed but after a few seconds it gets slower.What can i do to make the animation speed uniform?
Here's my code :-

```
 for (var j = 0; j < 30; j++)
            {
                crazyNumbers[j] = document.createElement("ul");
                crazyNumbers[j].id = "list" + j;
                document.getElementById("dynamic").appendChild(crazyNumbers[j]);
                crazyNumbers[j].style.listStyleType = "none";
                crazyNumbers[j].style.marginLeft = (j * 40) + "px";
            }




                 dynamicList[0] = setInterval(function () {

                         var li = document.createElement("li");
                         animatedNumber = parseInt(Math.random() * 10);

                         li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(animatedNumber));
                         crazyNumbers[0].appendChild(li);
                         $("#list0").animate({ marginTop: '-=80px' }, 90);

                 }, 90);
                 dynamicList[1] = setInterval(function () {

                     var li = document.createElement("li");
                     animatedNumber = parseInt(Math.random() * 10);

                     li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(animatedNumber));
                     crazyNumbers[1].appendChild(li);
                     $("#list1").animate({ marginTop: '-=80px' }, 95);

                 }, 95);
```

Comment: Please try to whittle this down. You have posted a huge wall of code; we are not going to go through all of that looking for potential problems.

Comment: like this i am animating all the remaining 28 ul elements....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it that surprising that your window cannot keep up. From what I can read from the code, you're creating about 300 new li elements every second, as well as making 300 requests to animate some kind of ul. The more li elements the ul has, the more intense it becomes to animate it.

It's important to note  that  setInterval has no clue about how well the window is keeping up performance.  So for example:

```
setInterval(function () {
                         $("#list0").animate({ marginTop: '-=80px' }, 90);
                 }, 90);
```

Is not good, because there is no guarantee that javascript will have finished its animation after 90ms, especially if you're pushing it like you do.

A simple way that might lessen this problem would be to finish any previous animations that are running on the element

```
setInterval(function () {
                         $("#list0").finish().animate({ marginTop: '-=80px' }, 90);
                 }, 90);
```

But perhaps a better way would be to do something like this

```
function loopAnimateList ($mylist, duration){
     animatedNumber = parseInt(Math.random() * 10);
     $myList.append(window.toStaticHTML('<li><text>' + animatedNumber + '</text></li>'))
            .finish()
            .animate({ marginTop: '-=80px' }, duration, null, function(){loopAnimateList($myList, duration);});
}

$('ul').each(function(){loopAnimateList($(this), 90)});
```

And just call this function after creating the lists, not using setInterval at all.

But if you keep spawning list elements like that, it's just delaying the inevitable.

Comment: To correct some errors ,I've used this code in line 3 of your mentioned code:-               $myList.append(window.toStaticHTML('<li><text>' + animatedNumber + '</text></li>'))

Comment: Now the animation speed is uniform but now it's comparatively very slow to prior.The speed is not as per the code i.e. 80px/90ms.  What should i do know?

Comment: Thanks I'll correct the code. And yeah none of the ways can actually guarantee 80px every 90ms. I think the key lies in controlling the amount of list elements you have to animate. One more thing I can think of that might help you out, is to try using greensock's  gsap library (just google it).  It's a jQuery plugin that overrides the default animation methods with its own, more performant ones. You don't need to change any of your code to make it work, just include the library. Might give your application the edge it needs.